# Will changing to Ubuntu 15.04 affect steam big picture login?

Tags: 14.10, 15.04, steam

I would like to upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04 from 14.10 using a package last supported by Ubuntu 14.10. I installed the PPA on this site. https://launchpad.net/~thor27-gmail/+archive/ubuntu/steam-desktop
So my question is can I upgrade or will it not work? I would also love to have the steam application work as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will changing to Ubuntu 15.04 affect steam big picture login?

No. To be on the safe side: it should not affect it.

In general you need to disable (or delete) every PPA before upgrading. And you can re-enable (or re-install) those after you are using 15.04 to be on the very safe side.

You can always re-install steam big picture login using the 14.10 version of the software by doing the same installation on your new system. Ie. use ...

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/thor27-gmail/steam-desktop/ubuntu utopic main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/thor27-gmail/steam-desktop/ubuntu utopic main
```

instead of using vivid. Mixing releases for steam big picture login is not going to be a problem.

Comment: What about steam itself?

Comment: I  have had no troubles with steam on 15.04. So I would claim: it will work ;)

Comment: I am about to upgrade wish me luck

Comment: Upgraded ubuntu with no issues to the steam big picture

Comment: Gratz! and happy gaming.